# Databricks JDBC with Pyspark returning rows all rows as columns name

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to access and query from Azure DataBricks but I have been getting all rows as column name.
I am following method for code.
Please give solution if anyone is aware of this.

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:databricks://<WorkspaceInstance>... <Token>")
.option("query", "query")
.option("user", "username")
.option("password", token)
.option("fetchsize", "10")
.option("driver", "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver")
.load()

df.show()

+-------+-------
|CustomerName  |
+-------+-------
|CustomerName  |
|CustomerName  |
|CustomerName  |
+-------+-------
```

Comment: Can you share option("query", "query") part of your code.

Comment: Searching Stackoverflow for similar issues suggests that the issue is with the driver. Make sure you have the latest version. https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download.

Comment: it's simple query like : query = f"select column1,column2,column3 from tableschema.tablename where start_date >= '2023-11-11' and end_date < '2023-11-15' limit 3 "

Comment: @ChenHirsh I am using the latest driver with Spark 3.1.2 and python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the names of the columns you are referring to in your SQL query exactly match the names of the columns in your table.
If any column has spaces or special characters, enclose them with **backticks (`)** to avoid any issues.

I have tried the below example and reading the data from Azure SQL:

Connection to Azure SQL database:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DateType
jdbcHostname = "dilipserver.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "db02"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};database={jdbcDatabase}"

connectionProperties = {
    "user": "dilip",
    "password": "Welcome@1"
}


custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField("RequestID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("CustomerName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("RequestType", StringType(), True),
    StructField("RequestDate", DateType(), True),
    StructField("Status", StringType(), True)
])
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM repair_request"
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", f"({sqlQuery}) AS repair_request_alias") \
    .option("user", connectionProperties["user"]) \
    .option("password", connectionProperties["password"]) \
    .option("fetchsize", "10") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("header", "true")\
    .schema(custom_schema) \
    .load()
df.show()
```

```
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|RequestID|CustomerName|RequestType|RequestDate|     Status|
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        1|    John Doe| Electrical| 2023-01-10|    Pending|
|        2|  Jane Smith|   Plumbing| 2023-02-15|In Progress|
|        3| Bob Johnson|       HVAC| 2023-03-20|  Completed|
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

from the above code I defined a custom schema `(custom_schema)` explicitly, which ensures that Spark won't infer column names from the first row of the data.

Specify the customSchema option when reading the data.
This option allows you to specify the schema of the data returned by the query, which can help the JDBC driver properly parse the data.

`.option("header", "true")` indicates that the first row of the data contains column headers.

Comment: Using driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
is giving error of java.lang.ClassNotFundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.
I am using latest version of Databricks JDBC with driver name : com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver - with this driver name I am not getting error of ClassnotfoundException but at the end I get same thing like all rows values as columnames.

Comment: can you try 
jdbcHostname = "<Azure sql server>"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "<Database>"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};database={jdbcDatabase}"
connectionProperties = {
    "user": "Username",
    "password": "Password"
}
and define schema

Comment: df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("user", connectionProperties["user"]) \
    .option("password", connectionProperties["password"]) \
    .option("fetchsize", "10") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .schema(custom_schema) \
    .option("dbtable", f"({sqlQuery}) AS repair_request_alias") \
    .load()
then try reading like this once.